# Save as the part of a file

Tags: javascript

I would like have a button and when you click this button, un can save save as a part of the file.

For example if in DOM there is:

```
<div>
  <div id="myButton">My Button</div>
  <h1>My Title</h1>
  <p>My Text</p>
</div>
```

Then when you click myButton the navigator opens a window for saving a file untitled "my button" with the content "My Text". Is it possible or should i use a pop up or anything else to do that?

Due to the risk of hacking, i dont think it's directly possible, but maybe a navigator plug in can do it ? Because i dont care for the support of cross-navigator, it's only for a personal use.

Thanks !

Comment: Hello, are you trying to save a file from web like uploading it to the web server ? the question is not so clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it with javascript alone, you need server-side script like PHP and then you have to send a ajax request to the server to page to save the text

Here is a scratch of what your code is going to look like

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    //show some saving somewhere

    $.post("yourserverpage.php", 
    { 
       //Send the data
       title : $(this).parent().chidren("h1").html(), 
       text : $(this).parent().chidren("p").html(),
    }, function(data) {
       //sucess
       // do something on success
    }
);
```